# jQuery ui multiple slider confusion with values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I am using for a short period ui slider utility and ended with the following situation. I have three sliders combined in order to use their result and alter an object's css box-shadow. This is my code:

```
$('#slider2, #slider3, #slider4').slider({
    range: 'min',
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    step: 1,
    animate: true,
    slide: function(x,y,z) {
        var x = $('#slider2').slider('value'),
            y = $('#slider3').slider('value'),
            z = $('#slider4').slider('value')
        $('#xShadowValue').val(x + ' px');
        $('#yShadowValue').val(y + ' px');
        $('#zShadowValue').val(z + ' px');          
        $('#target').css('box-shadow', x + 'px ' + y + 'px ' + z + 'px ' + '#888888');
    }
});

$('#xShadowValue').val($('#slider2').slider('value') + ' px');
$('#yShadowValue').val($('#slider3').slider('value') + ' px');
$('#zShadowValue').val($('#slider4').slider('value') + ' px');
```

Problem is when i change the first one all is fine. When i change the second one the first one drops or increases a unit same when i change the third occurs for the second one. Furthermore i cannot slide all of them to 0 or 100. A limit appears at 1 and 99 accordingly. Thanx in advance.

Comment: i didn't see you resetting the value.. Could that be the reason?

Comment: This is weird. Able to reproduce here: http://jsfiddle.net/aNjM6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are using `$("#slider").slider("value")` to retrieve the value.

This is *not* mentioned in the documentation from what I could see, but according to a note in [this bug ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7837), you should use `ui.value` to get the *new* value of the slider and the `value` method to get the *old* value of the slider. This explains both of your issues.

With that in mind, you have to tweak your code a bit so that you take advantage of `ui.value` for each slider.

I would change two things:

1. Use `data-*` attributes to designate which slider corresponds to which axis:

   ```
   <div id="slider2" class="slider" data-axis="x"></div>
   <div id="slider3" class="slider" data-axis="y"></div>
   <div id="slider4" class="slider" data-axis="z"></div>
   ```
2. Update your `slide` callback to leverage those attributes:

   ```
   var boxShadow = {
       x: 0,
       y: 0,
       z: 0
   };

   $('#slider2, #slider3, #slider4').slider({
       step: 1,
       animate: true,
       slide: function(event, ui) {
           var axis = $(this).data("axis");

           boxShadow[axis] = ui.value;

           $('#xShadowValue').val(boxShadow.x + ' px');
           $('#yShadowValue').val(boxShadow.y + ' px');
           $('#zShadowValue').val(boxShadow.z + ' px');            

           $('#target').css('box-shadow', boxShadow.x + 'px ' + boxShadow.y + 'px ' + boxShadow.z + 'px ' + '#888888');
       }
   });
   ```

Basically, keep a simple object that tracks x, y, and z. This object is easily updated using the aforementioned `data-*` attributes.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/t3gva/